# objective c and xcode assigning value to label coming from a NSInteger type variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

It's me again, I've been struggling with this for the past hour and a half and can't seem to find a good way of implementing this. I'm basically trying to display results on a label on clicking of  a button. (Just starting out with xcode so I'm not sure if that's the right term for that action). Anyway, here's my code and the method on my controller: I have

```
@interface Match : NSObject{
}
@property NSInteger *Id;
@property NSString *fighter1, *fighter2;
- (id) initWithWCFId:(NSInteger)matchId bracketId:(NSInteger)bracketId;
@end


@implementation Match
- (id) initWithWCFId:(NSInteger)matchId bracketId:(NSInteger)bracketId{
    self = [self init];
    if(self){
        self.Id = &(matchId);
        self.fighter1 = @"Person 1";
        self.fighter2 = @"Person 2";
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

--- controller ---

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    /*IBOutlet UITextField *txtFieldBracketId;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtFieldMatchId;*/
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtFieldBracketId;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtFieldMatchId;
- (IBAction)btnSubmit:(id)sender;

@end
```

--- implementation

```
- (IBAction)btnSubmit:(id)sender {

    @autoreleasepool {
        Match *match = [[Match alloc]initWithWCFId:[_txtFieldMatchId.text integerValue] bracketId:[_txtFieldBracketId.text integerValue]];

        self.lblMatchId.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSNumber numberWithInt:match.Id]];
        self.lblFighter1.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:match.fighter1];
        self.lblFighter2.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:match.fighter2];
    }
}
```

I basically have two text boxes.
Now when I click the button it'll get the value for those text boxes and then displays the data it got based off of those inputs. It'll then display the three following data:

Id, Fighter1 and Fighter2.

So what's happening is, when I click the button, the whole thing stops and gives me this error:

> NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x74656e0'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x1c90012 0x10cde7e 0x1d1b4bd 0x1c7fbbc 0x1c7f94e 0xae4841 0x2891 0x10e1705 0x18920 0x188b8 0xd9671 0xd9bcf
>   0xd8d38 0x4833f 0x48552 0x263aa 0x17cf8 0x1bebdf9 0x1bebad0 0x1c05bf5
>   0x1c05962 0x1c36bb6 0x1c35f44 0x1c35e1b 0x1bea7e3 0x1bea668 0x1565c
>   0x23dd 0x2305) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Now I'm not sure if 1. The way I designed my class is correct, using "NSInteger" for the property id. or
2. Assigning the Id integer to string (edit box) is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the issues with your `Id` property, the crash is coming from this:

```
self.lblMatchId.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSNumber numberWithInt:match.Id]];
```

You are trying to pass an `NSNumber` object as the argument to the `initWithString:` method. But this method expects an `NSString` value, not an `NSNumber`.

Update the three lines to:

```
self.lblMatchId.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:#"%d", match.Id];
self.lblFighter1.text = match.fighter1;
self.lblFighter2.text = match.fighter2;
```

I'm assuming `match.fighter1` and `match.fighter2` are NSString properties.

Comment: they are NSStrings. and thank you for explaining the cause of that error

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. The property should not be pointer type, so it should be `@property NSInteger Id;` and in `init` it should be just `self.Id = matchId;`
2. Make it to string by using `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", match.Id]`